# Visualforce page $Action for custom object

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I am trying to redirect to the object New action. however it works fine for standard object, but not for custom object. if I use "{!URLFOR($Action.**Account**.New)}", then it works perfectly fine.

I am trying to override the Custom object New button with the below VF page.

```
<apex:page standardController="Apprenticeship__c" >
   <script type="text/javascript">      
           var profile = '{!$Profile.Name}'; 

           if(profile == 'System Administrator'){               
               redirectTo('{!URLFOR($Action.Apprenticeship__c.New)}');           
               }           
           function redirectTo(target) {
              window.location.href = target;
            }
   </script>
   <apex:pageMessages/>
</apex:page>
```

**Error**: Screen is just flickering nothing is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the "override" option if you're redirecting to an overridden page, otherwise you'll just get an infinite loop (provide "true" as the fourth parameter to URLFOR). As a matter of principle, you don't need any JavaScript, either:

```
<apex:page standardController="CustomObject__c"
    action="{!IF($Profile.Name<>'System Administrator', null, URLFOR($Action.CustomObject__c.New, null, null, true))}">
    <apex:pageMessage severity="error" summary="You cannot do this" detail="You are not allowed to use this feature" />
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I was trying that but couldn't quite hit on the right parameters for `URLFOR`.  Probably a little easier from a readability perspective to invert the Boolean so `null` comes first. I think the `<apex:pageMessages/>` tag is also unnecessary here. Answer might also be improved by naming that fourth parameter. :)

Comment: @AdrianLarson Not a bad suggestion. I'll do that.

Comment: @sfdcfox: Perfect solution. clean and crisp. no Javascript:)

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you use the `action` attribute here and specify `nooverride=1`. I would use an `Apex` extension so that it can be unit tested. Something like the below.

**Page**

```
<apex:page standardController="MyObject__c" extensions="Demo" action="{!redirect}">
    <apex:pageMessage severity="FATAL" summary="No access" />
</apex:page>
```

**Extension**

```
public with sharing class Demo
{
    public Demo(ApexPages.StandardController controller) { }
    public PageReference redirect()
    {
        Profile runningProfile = [
            SELECT Name FROM Profile WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getProfileId()
        ];
        if (runningProfile.Name != 'System Administrator') return null;

        String prefix = SObjectType.MyObject__c.getKeyPrefix();
        return new PageReference('/' + prefix + '/e?nooverride=1');
    }
}
```